# $hKh^{-1}=K$ if and only if $h^{-1}Kh=K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

Suppose $G$ is a group and $K$ is a subgroup of $G$. If $h\in G$, is it true that

$$hKh^{-1}=K \Leftrightarrow h^{-1}Kh=K?$$

I am reading a proof on page 94 of Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra, 3rd edition.

I am guessing we have $h^{-1}hk\in K$ (the highlighted part) because the above statement holds. Could someone please verify?

[image]

Comment: It's the normalizing assumption, that's all.  The element $h^{-1}kh \in K$ and so the given element lives in $HK$.

Comment: Why $h^{-1}kh\in K$?

Comment: Because elements of $H$ belong to the normalizer of $K$. In particular, $h^{-1} \in H$.

Comment: Oh I got it... Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement is true.
Since $N_G(K)$ is a subgroup,
$$hKh^{-1}=K\iff h\in N_G(K) \iff h^{-1}\in N_G(K) \iff h^{-1}Kh=K$$ 
As stated in comment, you just have to notice that for $h\in H$, $h^{-1}\in H\le N_G(K)$. Hence $h^{-1}kh\in K$.

Comment: But without the assumption that $H \leq N_G(K)$, is it true?  I don't think so, but I'm too lazy to come up with the counterexample.

Comment: Still, great observation that it's a one-liner with the normalizer assumption.  (I'm sure $S_3$ gives a counterexample.)

Comment: @Randall it is always true that for $g\in G$, $$gKg^{-1}=K \Leftrightarrow g^{-1}Kg=K$$ This is because $N_G(K)$ is a subgroup. So the argument above can be used.

Comment: Oh, that's super obvious.  Embarrassing.

Answer (score 2):

If
$$hKh^{-1}=K$$
then
$$h^{-1}(hKh^{-1})h=h^{-1}Kh,$$
$$(h^{-1}h)K(h^{-1}h)=h^{-1}Kh,$$
$$eKe=h^{-1}Kh,$$
$$K=h^{-1}Kh.$$

If
$$h^{-1}Kh=K$$
then
$$h(h^{-1}Kh)h^{-1}=hKh^{-1},$$
$$(hh^{-1})K(hh^{-1})=hKh^{-1},$$
$$eKe=hKh^{-1},$$
$$K=hKh^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

For every $x\in G$, the maps $\lambda_x\colon G\to G$ and $\rho_x\colon G\to G$ defined by $\lambda_x(g)=xg$ and $\rho_x(g)=gx$ are bijections.

Thus, for $A,B\subseteq G$, the following are equivalent:

1. $A=B$;
2. $\lambda_x(A)=\lambda_x(B)$ (in other notation $xA=xB$);
3. $\rho_x(A)=\rho_x(B)$ (in other notation $Ax=Bx$).

Now it's just computing and observing that $x^{-1}xA=A$ and the other similar identities.